# Problem getting the image row where all pixels are white

Tags: c#, .net, image, image-processing, system.drawing

I am trying to find if the image is clipped from the bottom and if it is, then I will divide it in two images from the last white pixel row. Following are the simple methods I created to check clipping and get the empty white pixel rows. Also, as you can see this is not a very good solution. This might cause performance issues for larger images. So if anyone can suggest me better ways then it will be a great help:

```
private static bool IsImageBottomClipping(Bitmap image)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < image.Width; i++)
    {
        var pixel = image.GetPixel(i, image.Height - 1);
        if (pixel.ToArgb() != Color.White.ToArgb())
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

private static int GetLastWhiteLine(Bitmap image)
{
    for (int i = image.Height - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        int whitePixels = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < image.Width; j++)
        {
            var pixel = image.GetPixel(j, i);
            if (pixel.ToArgb() == Color.White.ToArgb())
            {
                whitePixels = j + 1;
            }
        }
        if (whitePixels == image.Width)
            return i;
    }

    return -1;
}
```

`IsImageBottomClipping` is working fine. But other method is not sending correct white pixel row. It is only sending one less row. Example image:

[image: Example Image]

In this case, row around 180 should be the return value of `GetLastWhiteLine` method. But it is returning 192.

Comment: you simply need to change this line `whitePixels = j + 1;` to `whitePixels++;`

Comment: So, what exactly do you define as "clipping"? You only seem to check whether the lowest row contains a non-white pixel.

Comment: @Nyerguds for my project clipping is a row of pixel not having all pixels of white color.

Comment: @AishwaryaShiva If my answer helped you resolve your problem, please accept it as answer. See also, _[Help: Someone answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)_

Comment: @nyerguds yeah I am working on it. Please give me sometime. My project got corrupted so I created a  new project from start. I will get back to you soon.

Answer (score 2):

All right, so... we got two of subjects to tackle here. First, the optimising, then, your bug. I'll start with the optimising.

The fastest way is to work in memory directly, but, honestly, it's kind of unwieldy. The second-best choice, which is what I generally use, is to copy the raw image data bytes out of the image object. This will make you end up with four vital pieces of data:

- The width, which you can just get from the image.
- The height, which you can just get from the image.
- The byte array, containing the image bytes.
- The stride, which gives you the amount of bytes used for each line on the image.

(Technically, there's a fifth one, namely the pixel format, but we'll just force things to 32bpp here so we don't have to take that into account along the way.)

Note that the stride, technically, is not just the amount of bytes used per pixel multiplied by the image width. It is rounded up to the next multiple of 4 bytes. When working with 32-bit ARGB content, this isn't really an issue, since 32-bit *is* 4 bytes, but in general, it's better to use the stride and not just the multiplied width, and write all code assuming there *could* be padded bytes behind each line. You'll thank me if you're ever processing 24-bit RGB content with this kind of system.

However, when going over the image's *content* you obviously *should* only check the exact range that contains pixel data, and not the full stride.

The way to get these things is quite simple: use `LockBits` on the image, tell it to expose the image as 32 bit per pixel ARGB data (it will actually convert it if needed), get the line stride, and use `Marshal.Copy` to copy the entire image contents into a byte array.

```
Int32 width = image.Width;
Int32 height = image.Height;
BitmapData sourceData = image.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
Int32 stride = sourceData.Stride;
Byte[] data = new Byte[stride * height];
Marshal.Copy(sourceData.Scan0, data, 0, data.Length);
image.UnlockBits(sourceData);
```

As mentioned, this is forced to 32-bit ARGB format. If you would want to use this system to get the data out in the original format it has inside the image, just change `PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb` to `image.PixelFormat`.

Now, you have to realise, `LockBits` is a rather heavy operation, which copies the data out, in the requested pixel format, to new memory, where it can be read or (if not specified as read-only as I did here) edited. What makes this more optimal than your method is, quite simply, that `GetPixel` performs a `LockBits` operation *every time you request a single pixel value*. So you're cutting down the amount of `LockBits` calls from several thousands to just one.

---

Anyway, now, as for your functions.

The first method is, in my opinion, completely unnecessary; you should just run the second one on any image you get. Its output gives you the last white line of the image, so if that value equals `height-1` you're done, and if it doesn't, you immediately have the value needed for the further processing. The first function does exactly the same as the second, after all; it checks if all pixels on a line are white. The only difference is that it only processes the last line.

So, onto the second method. This is where things go wrong. You set the amount of white pixels to the "current pixel index plus one", rather than incrementing it to check if all pixels matched, meaning the method goes over all pixels but only really checks if the *last* pixel on the row was white. Since your image indeed has a white pixel at the end of the last row, it aborts after one row.

Also, whenever you find a pixel that does *not* match, you should just abort the scan of that line immediately, like your first method does; there's no point in continuing on that line after that.

So, let's fix that second function, and rewrite it to work with that set of "byte array", "stride", "width" and "height", rather than an image. I added the "white" colour as parameter too, to make it more reusable, so it's changed from `GetLastWhiteLine` to `GetLastClearLine`.

One general usability note: if you are iterating over the height and width, do actually call your loop variables `y` and `x`; it makes things a lot more clear in your code.

I explained the used systems in the code comments.

```
private static Int32 GetLastClearLine(Byte[] sourceData, Int32 stride, Int32 width, Int32 height, Color checkColor)
{
    // Get color as UInt32 in advance.
    UInt32 checkColVal = (UInt32)checkColor.ToArgb();
    // Use MemoryStream with BinaryReader since it can read UInt32 from a byte array directly.
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(sourceData))
    using (BinaryReader sr = new BinaryReader(ms))
    {
        for (Int32 y = height - 1; y >= 0; --y)
        {
            // Set position in the memory stream to the start of the current row.
            ms.Position = stride * y;
            Int32 matchingPixels = 0;
            // Read UInt32 pixels for the whole row length.
            for (Int32 x = 0; x < width; ++x)
            {
                // Read a UInt32 for one whole 32bpp ARGB pixel.
                UInt32 colorVal = sr.ReadUInt32();
                // Compare with check value.
                if (colorVal == checkColVal)
                    matchingPixels++;
                else
                    break;
            }
            // Test if full line matched the given color.
            if (matchingPixels == width)
                return y;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

This can be simplified, though; the loop variable `x` already contains the value you need, so if you simply declare it *before* the loop, you can check after the loop what value it had when the loop stopped, and there is no need to increment a second variable. And, honestly, the value read from the stream can be compared directly, without the `colorVal` variable. Making the contents of the y-loop:

```
{
    ms.Position = stride * y;
    Int32 x;
    for (x = 0; x < width; ++x)
        if (sr.ReadUInt32() != checkColVal)
            break;
    if (x == width)
        return y;
}
```

For your example image, this gets me value 178, which is correct when I check in Gimp.